# запрет doubleclick на заголовке datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

вытаскивыаю данные из mysql в datagridview. и при двойном щелчке по строке рисуется новое окно с подробной инфо. но тот же doubleclick срабатывает и на column header'е с передачей методу выделенной строки. как запретить двойной клик на заголовке?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){

var o=sender as DataGridViewCell;

if (!(o is DataGridViewHeaderCell)){}   //не работает

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для заголовка свойство `RowIndex` у `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` равно -1, соответственно можно сделать проверку это свойства, и на основании этого делать или не делать что-то:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    //тут что-то делаем
}
```